# Why location icon remains on even if I killed foursquare from background

Tags: ios, core-location, foursquare

I had done loads of R&D on locations services and I come to know that if you kill app from background then there is no way you can get location update.
but now I observed even if I kill Foursqure from background it still uses location services as location icon is present on the top, Once I turn off location services for foursquare location icon gets disappeared from top. 
please guide me how foursquare do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apps can register to get deferred location updates. This means that the OS can accumulate location data and feed it to the app later when the program is launched. Perhaps this is what's going on with Foursquare?

From Apple docs:

> In iOS 6 and later, you can defer the delivery of location data when
>   your app is in the background. It is recommended that you use this
>   feature in situations where your app could process the data later
>   without any problems. For example, an app that tracks the user’s
>   location on a hiking trail could defer updates until the user hikes a
>   certain distance and then process the points all at once. Deferring
>   updates helps save power by allowing your app to remain asleep for
>   longer periods of time.

Comment: this was not there in previous versions of iOS 7. I am currently on beta 5. is there any new update in 7.1 beta where we can get user's location on request from another device?